# ColdFusion: #URLSessionFormat("index.cfm?foo=bar")# -> two questionmarks in URL when cookies disabled

Tags: url, coldfusion, session-variables, session-cookies

My form looks something like this:

```
 <form name="foo_contact" action="<CFOUTPUT>#URLSessionFormat("index.cfm?foo=bar")#</CFOUTPUT>">
```

When I disable cookies and submit the form my URL looks like this:
`index.cfm?foo=bar?CFID=12345&CFTOKEN=12312312` which is not what I expected. It should read `index.cfm?foo=bar&CFID=12345&CFTOKEN=12312312`

Am I doing something wrong here? Do I need to write a function by myself to fix it or is there an easy solution I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple option - use a hidden form var instead.

```
<form name="foo_contact" action="<CFOUTPUT>#URLSessionFormat("index.cfm")#</CFOUTPUT>">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
```

Alternative option - change the relevant `?` to a `&` afterwards:

```
<cfset ActionUrl = URLSessionFormat("index.cfm?foo=bar")
    .replaceFirst('(?<!^index\.cfm)\?','&') />

<form name="foo_contact" action="<cfoutput>#ActionUrl#</cfoutput>">
```

This `.replaceFirst` uses a regex with negative lookbehind (the `(?<!`..`)` part) to find the first `?` that is not preceeded by `index.cfm` and replaces it.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I'll give the second option a try because the form is already in use and I don't want to mess up my colleague's code.

Comment: On the page `index.cfm?foo=bar` is another form and if I use `URLSessionFormat` in the action-attribute, the URL to the third page gets not only added CFID/CFTOKEN but also `;jsessionid=123123123123123123123123` which messes up the structure of the URL again. Any idea why there is a jsessionid added?

Comment: To clarify my question a bit more: the problem with the second's form action is that the order of the URL-params generated by URLSessionFormat is broken. It reads: `index.cfm;jsessionid=8412312312382728123123426e0c5542714e14?CFID=123123&CFTOKEN=123123123`

Comment: Pretty sure CF will still accept that URL? (The semi-colon is accepted as a path_info delimiter in Tomcat and JRun). If not replace `;jessionid[^?]+` with blank to remove it.

Comment: I ended up with stripping it out and just use CFID/CFTOKEN (session is still working without jsessionid in the URL so that's okay) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like so:

```
#URLSessionFormat("index.cfm")#&foo=bar
```

Comment: `index.cfm&foo=bar` is not a valid URL

Comment: `index.cfm&foo=bar` is NOT a valid URL. [UrlSessionFormat](http://cfdocs.org/UrlSessionFormat) only modifies the URL if cookies are not accepted.

Comment: wouldn't URLSessionFormat treat it the same since cookies are disabled?

Comment: Treat what the same? Cookies being enabled/disabled varies per client. (There is no mention of this being an intranet app with controlled clients - and given that the form name is given as foo_contact, it seems more likely this is a contact form on a public facing website.)

Comment: the question states "when cookies disabled" does URLSessionFormat not work when cookies are disabled vs cookies not accepted?

Comment: from the URLSessionFormat docs - "If the detected cookie is not turned on, or cookie support cannot be reliably detected, the function return value is as follows: myactionpage.cfm?jsessionid=xxxx;cfid=xxxx&cftoken=xxxxxxxx"

Comment: The question states "when I disable cookies..." - how else would you describe the action of selecting this option: http://imgur.com/q05bx ?   The OP almost certainly needs behaviour that works _both_ with and without cookies, and this answer doesn't provide that.

Comment: Sorry, but it wasn't clear to me he wanted both options, since he didn't mention that anywhere in his question. I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but like @PeterBoughton correctly guessed, it is a contactform and should work for users who don't accept cookies and users who accept cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of the potential security issues when using CFID and CFTOKEN.  These issues can be remedied by simply using J2EE session management instead.  Here is an excerpt from the [ColdFusion documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html):

**Client identifiers and security**

The following client identifier issues can have security implications:

- Ensuring the uniqueness and complexity of the CFToken identifier
- Limiting the availability of Session identifiers

The next sections discuss these issues.

**Ensuring CFToken uniqueness and security**

By default, ColdFusion uses an eight-digit random number in the CFToken identifier. This CFToken format provides a unique, secure identifier for users under most circumstances. (In ColdFusion, the method for generating this number uses a cryptographic-strength random number generator that is seeded only when the server starts.)

However, in the ColdFusion Administrator, you can enable the Settings page to produce a more complex CFToken identifier. If you enable the Use UUID for cftoken option, ColdFusion creates the CFToken value by prepending a 16-digit random hexadecimal number to a ColdFusion UUID. The resulting CFToken identifier looks similar to the following:

```
3ee6c307a7278c7b-5278BEA6-1030-C351-3E33390F2EAD02B9
```

**Providing Session security**

ColdFusion uses the same client identifiers for the Client scope and the standard Session scope. Because the CFToken and CFID values are used to identify a client over a period of time, they are normally saved as cookies on the user’s browser. These cookies persist until the client’s browser deletes them, which can be a considerable length of time. As a result, hackers could have more access to these variables than if ColdFusion used different user identifiers for each session.

A hacker who has the user’s CFToken and CFID cookies could gain access to user data by accessing a web page during the user’s session using the stolen CFToken and CFID cookies. While this scenario is unlikely, it is theoretically possible.

You can remove this vulnerability by selecting the Use J2EE Session Variables option on the ColdFusion Administrator Memory Variables page. The J2EE session management mechanism creates a new session identifier for each session, and does not use either the CFToken or the CFID cookie value.

**Security-related changes**

The following security-related specifications apply when you upgrade to ColdFusion 9 Upgrade 1:

- CFID, CFTOKEN, and jsessionid are marked httpOnly. This reduces the chance of session information being compromised on Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attack.
- Set the following system property for the session cookies to be httpOnly: Dcoldfusion.sessioncookie.httponly=true
- The support for session cookies to be httpOnly depends on the application server you use:

  - For Tomcat/JBoss, httpOnly is not supported for JSESSIONID
  - On JRun, add the system property, Dcoldfusion.sessioncookie.httponly=true , in the jvm.config file
  - For other application servers, see the relevant documentation for details on httpOnly support for session cookies.